How to determine the probability of unproportionality given a number of randomly chosen representatives, $r$, from a population, $n$?
Given an electoral system where the representatives, of population $r$, were chosen randomly from the electorate, of population $n$ (referred to as sortition), the total number of ways that the representatives could be chosen, $L$, would be
$$
L = \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
$$
Assuming that people can be split into $i$ unique and non-overlapping groups, $n$ is the sum of $i$ groups, $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_i$, which is some multiple, $\alpha$, of the number of representatives, and $r$ is the sum of $i$ represented groups $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_i$, the ideal outcome for an election under such a system would be a perfectly proportional representation such that
$$
n = \sum_{k=1}^i n_k = \alpha r = \alpha \sum_{k=1}^i r_k
$$
That is to say: $n_1 = \alpha r_1$, $n_2 = \alpha r_2$, $n_i = \alpha r_i$.
The law of large numbers states that "the average of the results obtained from a large number of independent random samples converges to the true value [source]", so the larger the number of electors, the lower the probability of an unproportional result, but there is still some probability of an unproportional result. I would like to determine the probability of an unproportional result given a number of electors and a number of representatives — specifically I want to know how much a group could be expected to deviate from its proprotional representation, and what the probability would be of such a deviation.
